# Does "zero configuration" need a hyphen when used attributively?

Tags: hyphenation

If you're talking about a piece of software that does not need to be configured, would it be a "zero configuration app" or "zero-configuration app"?

Comment: (b) I can see examples of both on the internet. (a) More importantly, is one likely to confuse?

Comment: I don't think it's _likely_ to confuse, but plausible. For example: is this something that configures zeroes? :P